# SlidingTabLayout: replace with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, pagerslidingtabstrip

I've the following situation:

- Linear Layout

  - ToolBar
  - SlidingTabLayout
  - ViewPager
  - FrameLayout

Initially, I only add a fragment to the FrameLayout, and all works. Next I remove this fragment, create new Adapter, and bind adapter to the SlidingTabLayout. All works again, but now I need to set tab visibility to false, and I do this with

```
slidingTabLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

but I also need to replace the current view with a new fragment.
Usually I do this with:

```
getFragmentManager().replace(parent, newFragment);
```

but now I can't do this because 
    getFragmentManager().replace(ViewPager, newFragment);
doesn't works. So how can I do this? And if is possible, can I add the ViewPager replacing in the backstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution. I made the following update to my layout:

- Linear Layout

  - ToolBar
  - Linear Layout (id: parentScroll)

    1. SlidingTabLayout
    2. ViewPager
  - Frame Layout (id: parent)

So when I need to hide all the tabs and the ViewPager, in order to inflate a new Fragment in the Frame Layout, I do the following:

```
 parentScroll.setVisibility(View.GONE);
 MyFragment myFragment= new MyFragment ();
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 transaction.add(R.id.parent, myFragment, "MYTAG");
 transaction.commit();
```

In the **onBackPressed** of this new fragment:

```
 MyFragment myFragment= (MyFragment) getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("MYTAG");
 if (myFragment!= null && myFragment.isVisible()) {
     parentScroll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(myFragment).commit();
 }
```